# Django-like templates system for Java?

Tags: java, templates, django-templates

I'm looking for the templates engine for Java with syntax like in Django templates or Twig (PHP). Does it exists?

Update:
The target is to have same templates files for different languages.

```
<html>
{{head}}
{{ var|escape }}
{{body}}
</html>
```

can be rendered from python (Django) code as well as from PHP, using Twig. I'm looking for Java solution.

Any other templates system available in Java, PHP and python is suitable.

Comment: I think this is a very interesting question!  So essentially you're looking for template engines that are cross-language/framework where you can use the same template while swapping out the entire rest of the tech stack.

Comment: I would LOOOVE django-like templating engine.

Comment: the best java alternative I've found is https://pebbletemplates.io/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- http://www.jangod.org/ (There is now also https://github.com/HubSpot/jinjava)
- run django via jython on jvm
- use http://mustache.github.com/

Comment: Sarvash, did you have any luck with either of these suggestions?

Comment: There is a comparison of some [web templating engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_engine_%28web%29) on wikipedia.

Comment: After checking out the jandgod project - I am really scared to use it. The code is horrible (all kinds of magic numbers, commented out sections), and haven't been updated since may 2010. It's great idea, unfortunately badly implemented...

Comment: I've contacted the Jangod author and he said he will not have time for this project for another half a year... But there is a fork on GitHub.

Comment: There is also https://github.com/HubSpot/jinjava

Comment: another option: https://pebbletemplates.io/

Answer (score 22):

I've developed [Jtwig](http://jtwig.org). You could give a try. It's being used in some projects with success. It's easy to setup with a nice integration with spring webmvc.

Just include the dependency using maven or a similar system.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.lyncode</groupId>
  <artifactId>jtwig-spring</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

And configure the view resolver bean to return the Jtwig one.

```
@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    JtwigViewResolver viewResolver = new JtwigViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".twig");
    return viewResolver;
}
```

Or, if you use xml base configurations:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="com.lyncode.jtwig.mvc.JtwigViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
  <property name="suffix" value=".twig"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: The project jtwig is no longer maintained.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the same templates for different languages, you might take a look at Clearsilver.

Clearsilver is a language-neutral template engine which helps separate presentation from code by inserting a language-neutral hierarchial data format (HDF) between your code and templates. Think of HDF like XML, but much simpler.

It's is used for many high-traffic websites, including Yahoo! Groups, Gmail Static HTML, orkut.com, wunderground.com, and others. Implementation languages used with it include C/C++, Python, Java, Ruby, PHP, C#, and others. The Python framework also includes a Page-Class dispatcher and simple ORM which is a bit Ruby-On-Rails like in that it makes mapping between database tables, HDF, and templates take very little code.

The main Clearsilver implementation is in C with language-specific wrappers. There is also a 100% java implementation made by Google and open-sourced called JSilver.

http://www.clearsilver.net/

http://code.google.com/p/jsilver/

Answer (score 0):

Sure, there are all sorts of template engines for Java.  I've used FreeMarker, Velocity and StringTemplate.  I'm not sure what you mean by Django-like syntax; each engine has it's own variations on a templating approach.

For a comparison of some different engines check out [here](http://java-source.net/open-source/template-engines).

Comment: I am pretty sure "Django-like syntax" means that syntax is similar to that in django: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/

Comment: Why to answer if you even don't know what the question was asked about...

Comment: Because when I answered the question 3 years ago, it didn't have all of the details after Update: The target is to have same...

Look at just the first line of the question and explain to me how it's inappropriate to prod for more info?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Mustache.java](https://github.com/spullara/mustache.java) and [Handlebars.java](https://github.com/jknack/handlebars.java). Mustache is very minimalistic. Handlebars is similar and compatible with Mustache, but you can **very easily** write your own extensions.